# How to change the initial value Chart.js-RangeSlider?

Tags: javascript, charts, nouislider

The Chart.js-RangeSlider doesnt starts at the `initial` value given (1901, 1910) and shows the chart:

[image]

What i'm searching is changin the `initial` value, and get the image below:

```js
[..snip..]

rsLluviaHistorica = new RangeSliderChart({
  chartData: iniDataLluviaHistorica,
  chartOpts: optionsLluviaHistorica,
  chartType: 'line',
  chartCTX: iniLluviaHistorica,
  //class: 'my-chart-ranger',
  initial: [1901, 1910]        
})

//this doesnt work
rsLluviaHistorica.options.initial = [1901, 1910]
```

[image]

The code: https://jsfiddle.net/sckull/hy0p75cq/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

The `initial` value has to be in range of the length of the data (0 to 112 in my case):

```js
rsLluviaHistorica = new RangeSliderChart({
  chartData: iniDataLluviaHistorica,
  chartOpts: optionsLluviaHistorica,
  chartType: 'line',
  chartCTX: iniLluviaHistorica,

  //range of 0 - 112
  initial: [0, 10]        
})
```

Solved: https://jsfiddle.net/sckull/hy0p75cq/16/